# Python: Visual difference widget

Tags: python, diff, pygtk, visual-diff

I'm planning to write a git client, and want to implement its UI with pygtk.
As we know, to show the different between two files is very important with respect to my project.

So, how can I make it in pygtk? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just delegate to meld?

Comment: Or to diffuse (http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I mean a widget actually, instead of another independent program.

Comment: I agree with Ignacio, [`meld`](http://meldmerge.org/) is excellent. Unless this is some instructional/educational exercise?

Comment: @PreetKukreti indeed. I'd like to implement some features just like ones in meld.

Comment: @ymfoi Don't reinvent the wheel. It's a waste of time. Meld is open source, so unless prevented by the license, copy Meld's custom widget!

Comment: @ptomato Well, there's no explicit documentation which shows where the widget is.